# iframe with menu drop down ontop of flash makes flash unclickable

Tags: html, css, flash

I've made a site where an iframe calls to a top navigation element, with a javascript drop down menu. I have it working where the menu drops over a center flash element, but even when the menu is not "dropped" - any element in that area on the flash does not respond to clicks.

I've changed z indexes, and now i cant seem to get the flash file to even be ontop of the iframe -

heres a link

http://schweigert-effect.com/testing/collections.html

heres the code -

```
    <body>
<div id="wrapper"><center>


  <div id="headerwrap">
   <iframe src="topnav.html" name="topFrame" scrolling="No" noresize="noresize" id="topnav" title=" topFrame"  frameborder="0" height="230px" width="900" allowtransparency="true">    <p>Your browser does not support iframes. please update</p>
   </iframe>
 </div> 

  <!-- 
  end #header
   -->

  <div id="page">
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="1100" height="650" id="Aico" title="Aico">
      <param name="movie" value="flash/home.swf" />
      <param name="quality" value="high" />
      <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
      <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />
      <!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don’t want users to see the prompt. -->
      <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
      <!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
      <!--[if !IE]>-->
      <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flash/home.swf" width="1100" height="650">
        <!--<![endif]-->
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />
        <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
        <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
        <div>
          <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
          <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" width="112" height="33" /></a></p>
        </div>
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
      </object>
      <!--<![endif]-->
    </object>
    <!-- end #page -->
  </div>
```

heres the code for the iframe html

```
<body style="background-color:transparent">

<div id="topnav">

<!--   top image   -->

  <div id="header"> <a href="news.html"><img src="images/topheader.jpg" alt="Home" width="312" height="75" border=0/></a></div>


  <!-- top menu  -->
  <div id="topmenu">
    <ul class="menu" id="menu">
```

Comment: can i have any url to see the page?

Comment: http://schweigert-effect.com/testing/collections.html

- youll see the explore menu drop down goes over the flash  - but you cant select the dragger or anything else within the iframe size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to set the window mode on the flash object to opaque.  I would need to see your code to tell you exactly how to do this, but it's basically setting this below:

```
wmode="opaque"
```

Comment: hi, thanks for getting back to me
i've tried opaque and transparent, neither fix it 
here is the code

Comment: Post the code in your original question otherwise we won't be able to read it.

Comment: ... ill make a link to read the code easier - 

http://schweigert-effect.com/testing/collections.html

Comment: It seems to work fine in Chrome, what browser are you testing with?  Also, not so sure an iFrame is really necessary at all.

Comment: i used an iframe because im going to be calling to that top nav across the whole site and didnt want to have to update it if changes were made - 

in chrome your able to drag the slider down? for me in chrome nothing in the top section of the page is selectable

Comment: You can use a server side include file instead, it is one file to have your code in, and is included on each page... but it's part of the page and not an iFrame: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes

Comment: Sorry I was able to click the buttons at the bottom, didn't notice the scrollbar... you're correct I can't use the scrollbar, it thinks you're clicking on the menu.

Comment: it works without the iframe - but i wanted to use it to keep the top nav dynamic across all the pages -

Comment: Read my comment above about using a server side include instead.  That would be a better solution here.

Comment: ok ill look into that , thank you :)

will it allow the overlapping drop down?

Comment: Yes it works just like if you had the code in each page separately.